# Compiler error when trying to pass two-dimensional array of pointers as const

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, constants, parameter-passing

I want to pass a two-dimensional array of pointers to a function in such a way that the function can neither change the integer values pointed to by the pointers of the array through dereference of these pointers, nor change the pointers themselves, nor cange the array itself ([see my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793690)):

```
void test(int const * const (* const array)[2]) {}

int main()
{
    int* array[2][2];
    test(array);
}
```

This doesn't work. I'm using Visual Studio on Windows and the function call in line 6 causes a build error (error code [C2664](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2664?view=msvc-170)):

'void test(const int *const (*const )[2])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int *[2][2]' to 'const int *const (*const )[2]'

Strangely enough, these two work perfectly fine:

```
void test(int const * const (* const array)) {}

int main()
{
    int* array[2];
    test(array);
}
```

```
void test(int* const (* const array)[2]) {}

int main()
{
    int* array[2][2];
    test(array);
}
```

What's the problem here?

Help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: a 2d static array (X[R][C]) is not the same as a one d array of pointers. They are laid out in memory quite differently. (I know you have arrays of pointers but forget that, its not relevant same would be true with purely int arrays)

Comment: Pointer hell!  Using `std::array` would make this easier